# Azure Function Host Threshold Exceeded Threads

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management

I have multiple Azure functions running on a consumption plan.  I also have API Management set up.  Inside Api Management we have 2 web tests that hit these functions every 3-5 mins and make sure they are still up and accessible.  The endpoint that the web test hit just has the below code.

```
[FunctionName("HealthCheck")]
    public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "healthcheck")]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info("Health Check Triggered");
        return Task.FromResult(req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK));
    }
```

After running for some time the function starts to 503 with the Host Threshold Exceeded [Threads] error.  I can't figure out what would be causing the issue.  Are there any limitations with Azure that prevent this from working due to the function being on a Consumption Plan instead of App Service Plan?  Thanks in advance for any information.

Comment: This thread might help - https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/973

Comment: Have you changed to a new service plan or existing?

Comment: This is an existing plan.  We had the function all set up and all was working, then we added the web tests and it started taking the functions down after about 14 hours of running tests.  We are going to switch it to an app service plan instead of consumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Host Health Monitor** feature is currently **only active on Consumption plan**, where these sandbox limits exist. The feature is enabled by default, but can be disabled/configured via the `healthMonitor` section of `host.json`, e.g.

```
{
    "healthMonitor": {
        "enabled": true,
        "healthCheckInterval": "00:00:10",
        "healthCheckWindow": "00:02:00",
        "healthCheckThreshold": 6,
        "counterThreshold": 0.80
    }
}
```

If your Function App is hitting thresholds, you'll see errors like `Host thresholds exceeded: [Threads]`  being logged. **Threads : Number of threads (limit is 512).**

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Host-Health-Monitor).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  We decided to switch the plan from a consumption plan to an app service plan.